# How do I index the data after group-by and resampling?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I have a timeseries data for a full year for every minute.

```
timestamp               day hour min rainfall_rate           
2010-01-01 00:00:00     1   0   0       x
2010-01-01 00:01:00     1   0   1       1
2010-01-01 00:02:00     1   0   2       2
2010-01-01 00:03:00     1   0   3       x
2010-01-01 00:04:00     1   0   4       5
...                            ...
2010-12-31 23:55:00     365 23  55      3
2010-12-31 23:56:00     365 23  56      9
2010-12-31 23:57:00     365 23  57      32
2010-12-31 23:58:00     365 23  58      12
2010-12-31 23:59:00     365 23  59      22
```

I used `sampled_df = rainfall_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).resample('D').sum()`, to group the data by month and calculate the daily sum of `rainfall_rate`.

Structure of `sampled_df`.
[image]
How to plot the monthly data against the timestamp for every months. How do I index `rainfall_rate`? I want the data of `rainfall_rate` daily for every month. Also is the grouping correct? Suppose I want to plot `timestamp vs rainfall_rate` for the month of `January`. How do I do that?

I am new to `pandas`.

Comment: How do you want the values to be indexed; What is your desired output? Would `.reset_index()` be sufficient?

Comment: Edited the question. How would `reset_index()` be used here?

Comment: *How do I index the values?* What values? If by `rainfall_rate`, usually data values are not indexed. If either timestamp or both, you can set any column(s) as index with [`DataFrame.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html). *Is the grouping correct?* You tell us. If output is in your expected desired result and renders your plot, then it is correct.

Comment: So, How do I plot `timestamp vs rainfall_rate` for the month of january? @Parfait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a plot from the resulting resampled data, simply call [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). However, since you have a multindex with two timestamps for month and day indicator, call [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to drop the redundant month level. And for specific month plotting, run boolean indexing on the day index for specific month:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

# RESET INDEX AND FILTER COLUMNS
sampled_df = (sampled_df.reindex(['rainfall_rate'], axis='columns')
                        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
             )

### ALL MONTHS
sampled_df.plot(kind='line')

### ONLY JANUARY
sampled_df[sampled_df.index.month == 1].plot(kind='line')
```

---

To demonstrate with random, seeded data:

**Data**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(22820)
rainfall_df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('2010-01-01 00:00', 
                                                       '2010-12-31 23:59', 
                                                       freq="min"),
                            'rainfall_rate': np.random.normal(1, 2, 525600)
                           })
```

**Resampling**

```
sampled_df = (rainfall_df.set_index('timestamp')
                         .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M"))
                         .resample('D')
                         .sum()
             )    

sampled_df.tail(10)
#             rainfall_rate
# timestamp
# 2010-12-22    1454.287302
# 2010-12-23    1367.539650
# 2010-12-24    1460.319823
# 2010-12-25    1464.392407
# 2010-12-26    1338.139227
# 2010-12-27    1454.540103
# 2010-12-28    1553.949133
# 2010-12-29    1301.670684
# 2010-12-30    1536.173442
# 2010-12-31    1333.492614
```

**Plots**

```
sampled_df = sampled_df.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

### ALL MONTHS
sampled_df.plot(kind='line')
```

[image: Year Plot]

```
### ONLY JANUARY
sampled_df[sampled_df.index.month == 1].plot(kind='line')
```

[image: Jan Plot]

Comment: 1. Why we have to use `reset_index()`?

2. Whenever I run `sampled_df[sampled_df.index.month == 1].plot(kind='line')` 
it gives `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'month'`

Comment: Hmmm... the output of `groupby(pd.Grouper(...)).reasmple().sum()` should have been a multindex of two timestamps. Specifically in your data block at *Structure of sampled_df.*, the two *timestamps* should be indexes (not regular columns) with its headers printed lower than *rainfall_rate*. In fact, to even use `pd.Grouper()`, original *rainfall_df* should be indexed on *timestamp*. Run [fiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/9b1ed0a9-5447-4b2a-a941-9c7f12fa89b2/?m=Saved%20fiddle) using your posted data.

Comment: Just noticed that your data has more columns than *rainfall_rate*, for that reason use `reindex` to subset only that column for plotting. See edit.

Comment: Just updated the question, my bad I didn't give the `sampled_df` format correctly. Please help now. @Parfait

Comment: What's more to help? Run this solution to drop first *timestamp* level index on *sampled_df* with `reset_index` then `plot`.

Comment: Thanks. That Worked. But I didn't understand why do we need to use `reset_index()`

Comment: Once again, you essentially run *two* aggregations by *timestamp*: with `Grouper` and `resample`. This results in a data frame with a Multindex of two *timestamp* indexes at month and daily level. We need to remove the first month *timestamp* index for a coherent plot. To see, run `plot` without `rest_index` and your x-axis will be hard to read with tuple pairs.